# Find the MOST popular minor of student in CS

Tags: mysql, sql

I am new in SQL so the question may be stupid.

Here is the a sample line of the related tables:
Student:

```
+-------+----------+---------+------+------+-------+---------+-----------+
| StuID | LName    | Fname   | Age  | Sex  | Major | Advisor | city_code |
+-------+----------+---------+------+------+-------+---------+-----------+
|  1001 | Smith    | Linda   |   18 | F    |   600 |    1121 | BAL       |
```

Minor_in:

```
+-------+------+
| StuID | DNO  |
+-------+------+
|  1004 |  520 |
```

Deparment:

```
+------+----------+--------------------------+------+--------------+--------+
| DNO  | Division | DName                    | Room | Building     | DPhone |
+------+----------+--------------------------+------+--------------+--------+
|   10 | AS       | History of Art           | 268  | Mergenthaler |   7117 |
```

I want to find the most popular minor of students in CS Major (DNO = 600)
Here is my query, it works but it's ugly:

```
SELECT DNO, count 
FROM (SELECT DNO, COUNT(*) AS count
      FROM Minor_in
      WHERE StuID IN (SELECT StuID
                      FROM Student
                      WHERE (Major = 550 OR Major = 600))
      GROUP BY DNO
) AS C1
WHERE count IN (
                SELECT MAX(count)
                FROM (
                      SELECT DNO, COUNT(*) AS count
                      FROM Minor_in
                      WHERE StuID IN (SELECT StuID
                                      FROM Student
                                      WHERE (Major = 550 OR Major = 600))
                      GROUP BY DNO
                      ) AS MinorCount
                );
```

Is there any better way?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Thanks! First time to use StackOverflow! Was going to change the format but your are just sooo fast! Thanks again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this?

```
select stuid.dno, count (*)
from stuid inner join student
on stuid.stuid = student.stuid 
where student.major in (550, 600)
group by stuid.dno
order by count (*) desc
```

I am assuming that dnos 550 and 600 are the computer science courses

Comment: if I take stuid as Student, then the join will give empty set since each student can major in only 1 department. But thanks anyway

Comment: @BersaKAIN: I missed the fact that the major is stored in the students table. I am rewriting the query.

Comment: That will show the order which is awesome. Do you know any other way of getting the all the entities with the largest count?

Comment: @BersaKAIN: I don't really understand your question. There is also a contradiction - "all" the entities [but] with the largest count? Only one entity will have the largest count.